# `is` comparsion of integer greater than 256

Tags: python, python-3.x

This unexpected behavior surprised me:

```
>>> a = 256
>>> a is 256
True
>>> b = 257
>>> b is 257
False
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because `int` up to 256 are cached: for larger ones a *new* object is constructed.

Comment: Looks like it's been already answered elsewhere. Thanks for quick answer anyway :)

Comment: Note that you should be comparing integer values by equality (`==`) not identity (`is`).